# What does variable _allowances mean?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, mapping, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts

i was trying to understand this [ERC20 Contract in OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol).
In 36th line there is a mapping which defines _allowances,
[image]
it is being used in multiple lines (120, 155, 177, 196, 311) and i don't get why? Can someone explain these detailed?
I'd appreciated your help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indicates if (and how much) a wallet (or a contract) can transfer another user (or contract) tokens. It's usually set with the `approve` method but there could other ways too like the `permit` method.

E.g. `_allowances[owner][spender] = 42` means that `spender` can transfer up to 42 `owner`'s tokens towards whoever wants (even itself). Note that after this transfer the allowance is decremented.

Often "infinite approvals" are done setting this value to the `uint256` max value (2^256-1).

Comment: Thank you for your explanatory